# Android drawable-nodpi not working?

Tags: android

My 64x64 png image is getting scaled down in a xxhdpi screen when it is placed in drawable-nodpi folder.

The code for decoding is:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inScaled = false;
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon, opts);
```

I'm drawing it in a view with canvas.

Ah, i also read other post that manifest needs to have specified minSDK and screen supports but i still seem to be unable to achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so if you print `icon.getWidth()`  and `icon.getHeight()` you get two different values from 64?

Comment: No, i got 64 and 64 but the image is a lot tinnier than in a mdpi screen.

Comment: so it is working, isn't it?

Comment: isn't nodpi folder meant to that the image will be shown as a 64x64 independent of screen density? i mean it looks as a 25x25 in xxhdpi.

Comment: nope, the only assurance you have is that the bitmap is not scaled with the density, ergo you will get always its original size in px

Comment: So i should have 5 different images  in different directories (mdpi, hdpi...) to support other densities?

Comment: If you want that they look the same on all the densities you support, yes you have to

Comment: Solved then, thanks Blackbelt!